# Access INSERT with nested SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, insert, ms-access-2013

Why does the following SQL statement not work?

```sql
INSERT INTO dialog (speaker, dialog_text) VALUES (
    (
        SELECT FIRST(id)
        FROM FIGURE
        WHERE char_name="Doe" AND forename="John"
    ),
    "Some text"
);
```

It produces this error:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query.

The single `SELECT` statement works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Access SQL `INSERT ... VALUES` statement will not let you use a subquery for one of the `VALUES`

Switching to an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, as Piotr [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35021992/77335) will work.

Or you could use an Access [Domain Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836861.aspx#Anchor_6) function, instead of a subquery, in your `INSERT ... VALUES` statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO dialog (speaker, dialog_text)
VALUES (
    DMin("id", "FIGURE", "char_name='Doe' AND forename='John'"),
    'Some text'
);
```

Comment: When i run this code in MS Access everthing works fine, but when i try to run it in C#, parametrized, i get a "To few parameters." exception. Do you know why? Shall i open a new thread for this question?

Comment: I think we would need to see the parameter query and the c# code which supplies the parameter values.  So, yes, that is different enough that it should be a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Following works:

```
   INSERT INTO dialog (speaker, dialog_text) 
            SELECT FIRST(id), "Some text"
            FROM FIGURE
            WHERE char_name="Doe" AND forename="John"
```

Comment: Would it work with a second `SELECT` statement? I could not figure out how.